# Programatically publishing Content Type in Content type Hub

Tags: 2013, content-type, feature-activation, content-type-hub

I have a custom content type which I am deploying to a Site collection in which content type hub is configured.
To use the content types in different site collection after the content type is deployed we have to perform three steps:

1) Publish the content type

2) Run the Content Type Hub timer job

3) Run the Content Type Subscriber timer job.

I found this blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaks/archive/2011/09/04/content-type-hub-publishing-and-subscribing-to-content-types-programmatically-c-code.aspx), which is doing the same in feature activation.

My Code

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            //bool remoteAdministratorAccessDenied = SPWebService.ContentService.RemoteAdministratorAccessDenied;
            try
            {
                //SPWeb spWeb = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
                //SPSite spSite = spWeb.Site;

                string contentTypeHubSiteURL = string.Empty;

                //System.Configuration.Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/", spSite.WebApplication.Name);

                // App settings are retrieved this way
                if (properties.Feature.Properties["CTHubUrl"] != null)
                {
                    contentTypeHubSiteURL = Convert.ToString(properties.Feature.Properties["CTHubUrl"].Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    contentTypeHubSiteURL = "hardcoded url";
                }


                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentTypeHubSiteURL))
                {
                    using (SPSite siteCtHub = new SPSite(contentTypeHubSiteURL))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb webCtHub = siteCtHub.RootWeb)
                        {
                            if (ContentTypePublisher.IsContentTypeSharingEnabled(siteCtHub))
                            {
                                ContentTypePublisher ctPublisher = new ContentTypePublisher(siteCtHub);

                                IEnumerable<SPContentType> spContentTypes =
                                    webCtHub.AvailableContentTypes
                                    .Cast<SPContentType>().Where(ct => ct.Group == "My group");

                                foreach (SPContentType spContentType in spContentTypes)
                                {
                                    ctPublisher.Publish(spContentType);
                                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    using (SPSite siteCtHub = new SPSite(contentTypeHubSiteURL))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb webCtHub = siteCtHub.RootWeb)
                        {
                            //SPWebService.ContentService.RemoteAdministratorAccessDenied = false;
                            SPWebApplication spWebApp = siteCtHub.WebApplication;

                            SPService saMMS = spWebApp.Farm.Services.Cast<SPService>()
                                .FirstOrDefault(s => s.TypeName == "Managed Metadata Web Service");

                            SPJobDefinition ctHubTimerJob = null;

                            //Run the Content Type Hub Job
                            //This timer job is associated with the MMS service application    
                            ctHubTimerJob = saMMS.JobDefinitions.Cast<SPJobDefinition>()
                                .FirstOrDefault(jd => jd.Title == "Content Type Hub");
                            if (ctHubTimerJob == null)
                            {
                                saMMS = spWebApp.Farm.Services.Cast<SPService>()
                                    .FirstOrDefault(s => s.TypeName ==
                                        "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Timer");

                                ctHubTimerJob = saMMS.JobDefinitions.Cast<SPJobDefinition>()
                                    .FirstOrDefault(jd => jd.Title ==
                                        "Content Type Hub");
                            }

                            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
                            ctHubTimerJob.RunNow();

                            while ((from SPJobHistory j in saMMS.JobHistoryEntries
                                    where j.JobDefinitionId ==
                                        ctHubTimerJob.Id && j.StartTime >
                                        startTime
                                    select j).Any() == false)
                            {
                                Thread.Sleep(100);
                            }

                            //Run the Content Type Subscriber Job
                            //This timer job is associated with the subscriber's web application
                            SPJobDefinition ctHubSubTimerJob = spWebApp.JobDefinitions.Cast<SPJobDefinition>()
                                .FirstOrDefault(jd => jd.Title == "Content Type Subscriber");
                            startTime = new DateTime();

                            startTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

                            ctHubSubTimerJob.RunNow();

                            while ((from SPJobHistory j in spWebApp.JobHistoryEntries
                                    where j.JobDefinitionId ==
                                        ctHubSubTimerJob.Id && j.StartTime >
                                        startTime
                                    select j).Any() == false)
                            {
                                Thread.Sleep(100);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                //SPWebService.ContentService.RemoteAdministratorAccessDenied = remoteAdministratorAccessDenied;
            }
        }
```

My feature is scoped at web level(also tried with SiteCollection level), but getting access denied error in this line

```
ctHubSubTimerJob.RunNow();
```

Also tried RunwithElevatedPrivelege, anyways I am having farm administrator privilege.

Am I doing something wrong? Are there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

> When a timer job instance is created, it is persisted to the farm
>   configuration database. Accessing this database for write purposes is
>   a privileged operation; as a rule of thumb, only the farm service
>   account (that is, the account under which OWSTIMER.EXE executes) or
>   accounts that explicitly have the rights required to carry out such an
>   operation on the config database (typically administrators) will
>   succeed.
>
> By default, attempting to instantiate a timer job from within the site
>   collection context is going to fail. Attempting the operation in an
>   elevated privilege block (via SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges) is
>   only going to result in the web application's application pool account
>   context being used instead of the current user context; this only
>   succeeds if the app pool account has rights to write to the farm
>   configuration database. If this happens, it's typically because (a)
>   the farm service account is being used in roles that it shouldn't be
>   in (to run content web apps, for example), or (b) extra permissions
>   have been granted to the application pool account. Both cases
>   represent a deviation from a best-practices operating model.

References:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036589/problem-in-creating-timer-job

[Run Sharepoint timer job programatically using RunNow() using account having non admin rights](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76125/run-sharepoint-timer-job-programatically-using-runnow-using-account-having-non)

http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/10/22/custom-spjobdefinition-and-access-denied-error/